# Is there any idea to disable hystrix indicator?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, hystrix

check /health endpoint, i want to  disable hystrix from below response.

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "details": {
    "hystrix": {
      "status": "UP"
    }
  }
}
```

checked [HystrixHealthIndicator](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/hystrix/HystrixHealthIndicator.java), there is no way to disable it.
Any solution here?

Comment: Looks i have to create a pr to make it work, add ConditionalOnProperty on HystrixHealthIndicator.

Comment: No need. It follows the normal boot convention for disabling health indicators with the key "hystrix"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

related configuration is well documented at [production-ready-endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html).

To disable all default indicators

```
management.health.defaults.enabled=false
```

To disable hystrix only

```
management.health.hystrix.enabled=false
```

For further investigation, please check [ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator.java).